# Querying calendar content provider over a month time, but display instances per day

Tags: android, android-calendar

We've got an application that places dots in a month view where calendar events occur. We're using the calendar content provider to polulate the view.

The only problem is we query the content provider around 30 times per month: 1 - 30 november. So we get the correct number of instances per day. This way the content provider itself utilizes recurrence rules and 'multi-day' events.
For instance:
We have an event that takes place from 4 - 9 november. 
Querying the content provider on a daily basis we'll get the event back at: 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 november. This is obviously correct. But this has a very negative effect on the performance. On the other hand if I query just once: 1-30 nov, I'll only get the same event back just once. So I need to do some calculations on my own to define in which cells the event should appear.

So then, I was wondering if there is an helper or utility that does this for me:
1 query: But 5 times a seperate instance for an event that occurs more then once in that timespan.

Comment: I think you should try to run the query on Instances using a non-standard projection that differentiates the returned records for each day. There must be some field that makes the 4, 5, etc. instances distinct from each other

Answer (score 0):

You can query the fields `rrule`, `dtstart` and `dtend` from the `CalendarContract.Events` URI and use them to calculate the specific dates. Check this [link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.3) for description on the field's meaning and also this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#RRULE).

Comment: Shouldn't you get what you want if you query for instances, instead of events https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#query-instances ?

Comment: For recurrence rules it does, only for events that have a different start and end-time it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check Instances table of Calendar database, I faced a similar performance issue and this table resolved that. It basically holds all the recurrences of events as a separate instances, in short if a event is bound to occur for next 5 days this table will have five entries for same event detailing its attribute.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Instances.html

Hope it helps,
Techfist